# for loop speed or alternative solution?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

I know Python isn't built for speed but I would like to improve the performance of the following code:

```
listA = [1,2]
listB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# pre-allocate for speed. Appending empty list is slower?
newList = ['NaN']*len(listB)

# Do I need a loop? Can I use something faster?
for n in xrange(len(listB)):
    if listB[n] % 2 == 1:
        newList[n] = listA[0]
    else:
        newList[n] = listA[1]
```

My issue is `listB` can get pretty large.

I have already pre-allocated memory for `newList` and used `xrange`. I believe these provide significant speed increases for large lists.

But do I even need a for loop at all since each loop is not dependent on the previous result. Does python have an array type?

Can I break up `listB` and run the operation in parallel similar to `parfor` in Matlab?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
For my problem, as listA gets bigger, listB gets exponentially bigger.

For each item in listB there needs to be a lookup in listA. Then a calculation is performed (not necessary modulo) and the result appended to newList. Then I do a statistical analysis on newList (say take an average for simplicity). newList will always be the same length as listB.

Comment: You don't need to preallocate anything, just loop over listB

Comment: Should `listB[1]` be `listA[1]`?

Comment: Yes. I've corrected. Thanks

Comment: How large can listB be? Also, do you really need to create a new list?

Comment: So you are saying listB grows as you iterate?

Comment: No it depends on my dataset I am analysing. listA is a given size but listB will be exponential relative to listA.

Comment: Yes, I will need the newList as I will perform analysis on the result

Comment: So what lookups are you doing in listA? If listA has 1k elements are you indexing every element at some point? I really think you need to look at numpy if you need to really increase performance

Comment: Depending on what classification the item in listB is, it will lookup a value in listA to use in a calculation.

Comment: How do you know which index to lookup? It is beginning to sound more like you need a dictionary

Comment: There will be a function inside the for-loop. eg. if an item in listB sits within a range, it will select a particular item listA

Comment: Yes but how is the index determined, are you using the lower end of the range as the index for listA?

Answer (score 3):

The shortest and, perhaps, fastest way would be using list comprehension:

```
newList = [listA[1 - x%2] for x in listB]
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `xrange` is not to gain speed; its purpose is to reduce memory usage. The difference between `range(N)` and `xrange(N)` is that the latter doesn't expand to a list of size N but to a small generator object.

A few tips:

- If your list is big, look into numpy. Numpy has efficient algorithms for array handling and uses native code internally.
- Modulo is slow (`if listB[n] % 2 == 1:`). Better use a bitwise operator (`if ListB[n]&1`) in this case.
- The `if` statement can go out: `newList[n] = listA[1-ListB[n]&1]` for each value of *n* in range. Invert the order of `listA` to get git of the `1-` and save another integer op.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension seems to cut some time:

```
listB = [i for i in xrange(1,1000000)]
start = clock()

listA = [1,2]

for n in xrange(len(listB)):
    if listB[n] % 2 == 1:
        newList[n] = listA[0]
    else:
        newList[n] = listB[1]

print "Time taken = %.5f" % (clock() - start)

>>> 0.21216
```

Compared to:

```
listB = [i for i in xrange(1,1000000)]
start = clock()

listA = [1,2]

newList = [listA[0] if i%2 == 1 else listA[1] for i in listB]

print "Time taken = %.5f" % (clock() - start)

>> 0.15658
```

Answer (score 1):

First, replace the modulo operator, `n % 2`, with the bitwise and operator, `n & 1`. Next, instead of accessing `listB` by index, just iterate through its items directly using `in`. You can remove listA entirely. These small improvements should should speed things up slightly.

```
newList = ((n & 1) + 1 for n in listB)
```

The real advantage of this code though, is that it is a generator comprehension, not a list comprehension. Although this doesn't make it any faster, it does make it much more memory efficient. That being said, it also has some disadvantages; you cannot access the entire list, and once you access a value it is gone. If you only intend on iterating through `newList` or performing some calculation on each item of newList this will be fine. If not, then make `newList` a list comprehension:

```
newList = [(n & 1) + 1 for n in listB]
```

Best of luck!

Comment: The question specifically asks about speed, this also only works of the values are actually o and 1 in listA

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The OP also seemed to be concerned about memory if he/she was using ``xrange``. And if the OP is asking about "improv[ing] the performance of the following code," I would say memory also falls into this category. Since the OP's question implied that this is his actual code, and not just a trivial example of what  he like to do, I think it's legitimate to assume that ``listA`` will always contain ``1`` and ``2``. If not, then the OP can make a minor adjustment to this code to account for the actual values of ``listA``.

Comment: *ADDITIONAL INFO: For my problem, as listA gets bigger, listB gets exponentially bigger.*,  how does using xrange and indexing a list help with memory? The lists are already stored in memory

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over listB and set two variables at the start instead of repeatedly indexing:

```
newList = []


i, j = listA[0], listA[1]
for n in listB:
    if n % 2:
        newList.append(i)
    else:
        newList.append(j)
```

Or use a list comp:

```
 [i if n % 2 else j for n in listB]
```

Timings:

```
In [4]: %%timeit
newList = ['NaN']*len(listB)
for n in xrange(len(listB)):
    if listB[n] % 2 == 1:
        newList[n] = listA[0]
    else:
        newList[n] = listA[1]
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.33 µs per loop

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: i,j = listA[0], listA[1]
   ...: [i if n % 2 else j for n in listB]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 µs per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
....: newList = []
....: i,j = listA[0], listA[1]
....: for  n in listB:
....:     if n % 2 == 1:
....:         newList.append(i)
....:     else:
....:         newList.append(j)
....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 µs per loop

In [18]: timeit [listA[1 - x%2] for x in listB]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 µs per loop
```

Using if n & 1 is slightly faster:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
i,j = listA[0], listA[1]
[i if n & 1 else j for n in listB]
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop
```

So indexing always adds more overhead whether in a list comp or a loop. It is pointless continually indexing listA when you just want the two values.

If you want more speed compiling with cython and simply typing a couple of variables cuts down the runtime:

```
In [31]: %%cython
   ....: def faster(l1,l2):
   ....:     cdef int i,j,n
   ....:     i, j = l1[0], l2[1]
   ....:     return [i if n & 1 else j for n in l2]
   ....: 

In [32]: 

In [32]: timeit faster(listA,listB)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 455 ns per loop
```

If you are doing a lot of numeric calculations you may want to look further into cython and or numpy.